series of books involving an American government agent, Eldorado, and the Nautilus submarine
A few years ago, I read a series of books that featured an Indiana Jones-style government agent mixed with James Bond. In these books some myths such as El Dorado, Area 51 are taken as real.
I also remember that one of the books talks about the existence of the Nautilus submarine from Jules Verne's book. All of these events occur in the first half of the 20th century, I am almost certain that he is an American writer.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you describe the covers of any of these books?  You read them in English or in translation?

Also can you tell us approximately when you read these books (and how many)?

The Nautilus submarine immediately made me think of the Dirk Pitt series by Clive Cussler. I don't think he got involved with Are 51 though (or El Dorado, though he did find "Inca Gold").

@ClaraDiazSanchez I don't think those books are set pre-WW2 though?  (Of course it's hard to reconcile "first half of the 20th century" and "Area 51" but...)

@DavidW True enough, but story ID questions can often be fuzzy on dates.

@DavidW I know there were at least 3 books, I read a Spanish translation.

Was Captain Nemo a character in the books?

@ClaraDiazSanchez the book mentioning Nautilus is presumably Valhalla Rising. I'd say it was worth an answer.

@JohnRennie Yes Valhalla Rising, or the Spanish title La cueva de los vikingos. I don't recall anything about Area 51 or El Dorado though.

@ClaraDiazSanchez That would be the Inca Gold novel that you mentioned.

@JohnRennie and Area 51?

OK, you got me there :-) But the OP said myths such as Eldorado, Area 51 so they may not have specifically meant Area 51 is mentioned in on of the books.

@JohnRennie I think it's a bit of a 50% hit-rate, but I'll put an answer together.

The question hits a number of points in Clive Cussler's Dirk Pitt series. The titular Dirk Pitt is a government agent, and definitely is an action-adventure hero, very much in the mold of James Bond/Indiana Jones.
Many of the books have been translated into Spanish. In particular the 15th in the series, Valhalla Rising was translated as La cueva de los vikingos and involves the discovery of Captain Nemo's Nautilus submarine. From a review on Goodreads:

After evidence from St. Julian Perlmutter found in Jules Verne’s home,
Pitt finds the cove found by the Vikings that not only contains their
longships but the actual Captain Nemo’s Nautilus with a prototype of
the revolutionary engines that the reclusive scientist deciphered and
improved.

The 12th book, Inca Gold (El oro de los incas) involves a search for treasure in South America, which somewhat resembles the El Dorado myth. I am not aware of any mentions of "Area 51", although it would not surprise me.

The Pitt books are all set around the time they were published, starting in 1976, which would exclude them from fitting "the first half of the 20th century." Unless the OP is misremembering.

"Unless the OP is misremembering" - this has been known to happen on story ID questions
